# Error con ionic run IOS

Tags: ios, ionic, iphone

Quiero correr mi app en mi iphone y me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar `ionic run ios`
 `

> ** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
>
> [....] Waiting up to 1 seconds for iOS device to be connected
>
> [....] Found iPhone 5s (Global/CDMA) 'Claudia'
>   (d5fbe771c3dfeb66cdd926de40b2937772896845) connected through USB.
>
> 2016-11-17 22:41:58.516 ios-deploy[3074:92100] [ !! ] Can't access app
>   path
>   '/Users/Hernan/Desktop/cap/saltala/firebase/master/platforms/ios/build/device/casaco.app'
>   : No such file or directory
>
> Error: Error code 253 for command: ios-deploy with args:
>   --justlaunch,--no-wifi,-d,-b,/Users/Hernan/Desktop/cap/saltala/firebase/master/platforms/ios/build/device/casaco.app`

Comment: Utilizo ionic pero en windows para Android, trataste de buscar el problema en el foro de el mismo framework

Comment: si amigo y aún nada.

Comment: Y pusiste el problema en el repositorio de ionic en github, seguro que te responden alli mas rapido

Answer (score 0):

Hay muchos `issue` sobre este tema. Para poder ejecutar una app `iOS` debes tener un perfil de desarrollador, que firma la aplicación. En este caso te recomiendo que en primera instancia hagas lo siguiente :

- Ejecuta ionic build ios
- Abre en XCode tu aplicación. (La puedes encontrar en ./platforms/ios/
- Espera a que cargue todo, conecta tu dispositivo al Mac, en la esquina superior derecha sale con que dispositivo quieres ejecutar.
- Aquí hay 2 opciones

  - 1) Selecciona el tuyo y dale Play. Generalmente la primera vez fallara y te dará el error que te digo yo. Debes seleccionar la opción que te dice "Solucionarlo" o algo así. Esperas a que cargues y podrás ejecutarlo.
  - 2) Si tu dispositivo tiene la ultima versión de iOS y tu Equipo no, debes actualizar. XCode te dirá que no puede compilar y debes actualizar XCode.

Ya con esto despues de poder ejecutarlo en tu dispositivo desde XCode, para ejecutar desde Ionic puedes ocupar `ionic run ios --device`

Comment: cual es la función de --device?

Comment: obligar a ionic a ejecutar la app en un dispositivo físico.